# Wordpress upload folder permissions 751

Tags: php, wordpress, file-permissions

I want to protect my images on my wordpress site. So I changed the folder permissions of the following folders to 751:
wp-content/uploads
wp-content/uploads/2018
wp-content/uploads/2018/11

However, now when I upload an image via the Media upload, the image is not shown.

Is there any way to keep 403 Error for the above folders while still being able to upload and see the images correctly in the wp-backend?

I know this can be done, because Ive seen this before, I just dont know how to apply it myself.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you changing file permissions on the folders?  And what do you mean by "protect your images"?  If you're referring to preventing hot-linking to your images, then you should probably be using .htaccess rules.  Otherwise, note that any static resource that you make publicly accessible on the web can be downloaded.  People used to disable right click to "prevent image theft", which was stupid because anyone who looked at source code or used WGET could still grab their images with ease.

Comment: @JustinR. what I want is that anyone going  directly to mysite.comwp-content/uploads and sub folders, will have a 403 error, so they cany see the directories. But, at the same time, the images and files, should be viewable on the site. We need to secure our things the best we can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured how to do this, but only know how to do it manually.

Part A.

Set permissions to 751 for the following folders:

wp-content/uploads

wp-content/uploads/2018

wp-content/uploads/2018/11

Every month, and year, you need to apply the settings for the new months folder.

Part B.

1. Upload images in the wordpress backend using media uploader. (Dont worry you cant see the images yet)
2. Then, in cpanel, go to the folder where those files have uploaded
3. Next, for all those files you uploaded, change permissions to 644 (it should have been 640 right after you uploaded them)

Comment: Again, .htaccess rules would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

A better to do this is to simply add the following code to the bottom of your .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

And you can keep your folder permission to the default 755 and not have to access your cpanel every time you upload a file.